# json_decode in php is returning null

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to encode a json string but it keeps returning null.  I've tried a few suggestion here on st

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/finance?output=json&start=0&num=200&noIL=1&q=[currency%20%3D%3D%20%22USD%22%20%26%20%28%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEMKT%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEARCA%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSE%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NASDAQ%22%29%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3E%3D%20-101%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3C%3D%20-3%29%20%26%20%28volume%20%3E%3D%20150001%29%20%26%20%28volume%20%3C%3D%20313940000%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3E%3D%2010%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3C%3D%20229301%29]&restype=company&ei=T5mTVKG5IYT1igKEoYHQCQ";

$obj = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($obj);
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: What does `$obj` contain before you run `json_decode` on it?

Comment: It looks like if you want to encode a string you have to use `json_encode` not `json_decode`.

Comment: @Verhaeren I'd assume he wants to take a string (that he gets form that URL) and decode it into an object / array.

Comment: @AlpineCoder I'm pointing the lack of consistency in the title of the question.

Comment: The URL he's referencing is already json - I would assume he wants to decode.  If you remove the json_decode line, what does var_dump reveal?

Comment: It displays the json in string format.

Comment: The string returned from `file_get_contents()` [does not seem to pass json lint validation](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/ce8157).

Comment: So I'm assuming this json need to be formatted in some way.  The json is from google so I'm 99% there's no error in there.  As to how it needs to be formatted is where I'm stuck

Comment: This might be helpful: [PHP reading invalid json with json_decode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729051/php-reading-invalid-json-with-json-decode). It specifically references google/finance. "The JSON feeds from Google always seem to be plagued with problems...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON doesn't support \x escapes, so it's invalid JSON by definition, hence why json_decode() returns null. Decoding the valid JSON \u0022 works fine.

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/finance?output=json&start=0&num=200&noIL=1&q=[currency%20%3D%3D%20%22USD%22%20%26%20%28%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEMKT%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEARCA%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSE%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NASDAQ%22%29%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3E%3D%20-101%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3C%3D%20-3%29%20%26%20%28volume%20%3E%3D%20150001%29%20%26%20%28volume%20%3C%3D%20313940000%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3E%3D%2010%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3C%3D%20229301%29]&restype=company&ei=T5mTVKG5IYT1igKEoYHQCQ";

$obj = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = trim($obj);
$obj = str_replace('\x', '\u00', $obj);
$obj = json_decode($obj,true);
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: The solution is indeed to convert the `\x` notation to `\u00` notation. `trim()` isn't necessary. Works like a charm!

Comment: @ Jasper N. Brouwer Yes its not needed. I have added it because the json data have whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
function convert($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback('#\\\\x([[:xdigit:]]{2})#ism', function($matches) {
        return htmlentities(chr(hexdec($matches[1])));
    }, $string);
}
$url = "https://www.google.com/finance?output=json&start=0&num=200&noIL=1&q=[currency%20%3D%3D%20%22USD%22%20%26%20%28%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEMKT%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEARCA%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSE%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NASDAQ%22%29%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3E%3D%20-101%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3C%3D%20-3%29%20%26%20%28volume%20%3E%3D%20150001%29%20%26%20%28volume%20%3C%3D%20313940000%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3E%3D%2010%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3C%3D%20229301%29]&restype=company&ei=T5mTVKG5IYT1igKEoYHQCQ";

$obj = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = convert($obj);
$obj = json_decode($obj);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($obj); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11729508/2171120) (and pointed out by @showdev already, thanks!) you should use their RSS API and parse that as XML instead, because Google does not deem it necessary to honour web standards (here, they fail at JSON; elsewhere, they fail at simple things like SMTP and especially IMAP).

JSON has a very detailed specification, and it is very easy to adhere to in generators. Making JSON parsing strict is recommended for security reasons – especially with external input. So please use Google’s RSS variant.

Comment: Did you even try using the rss option argument?  I would suggest you do before just adding an answer.