# Convert string to array php

Tags: php, json

I have a string like this:

```
{ArrivalTime:300, ProductID:198, ArrivalDate:21/07/2017}, {ArrivalTime:582, ProductID:397, ArrivalDate:22/07/2017}
```

I used json_decode() but it's not working;

I need return array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ArrivalTime] => 300
            [ProductID] => 198
            [ArrivalDate] => 21/07/2017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ArrivalTime] => 582
            [ProductID] => 397
            [ArrivalDate] => 21/07/2017
        )

)
```

Can you help me to do that? thanks.

Comment: Because this string is __not a valid__ json.

Comment: It's not the correct JSON format. That's why `json_decode()` function is not working.

Comment: json_decode() doesn't work because your data is not valid json. Maybe you can solve the issue at the source of your data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP reading invalid json with json\_decode();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729051/php-reading-invalid-json-with-json-decode)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

> str_split — Convert a string to an array

Syntax:

```
array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )
```

Example:

```
<?php

$str = "Hello Friend";

$arr1 = str_split($str);

print_r($arr1);

?>
```

Edit:

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => F
    [7] => r
    [8] => i
    [9] => e
    [10] => n
    [11] => d
)
```

Replace string name and array name your own.
Thank You.

Comment: did you test your code? It will not work as he wants. He have to check why his json string not formatted correctly.

Comment: Yes dude You can try it in simple way. M answer only how to convert string to array.

Comment: Actually, he is not asking this! @GanganiRoshan

Answer (score 1):

Run follow code to analyse it:

```
function strAnalyse($str){
        preg_match_all('/(?<={)[^{}]*(?=})/',$str,$match);
        $result = array();
        foreach($match[0] as $item){
            $one =array();
            $tmp = explode(',',$item);
            foreach($tmp as $kv){
                $a = explode(':',$kv);
                $one[trim($a[0])] = trim($a[1]);
            }
            array_push($result,$one);
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
}
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ArrivalTime] => 300
            [ProductID] => 198
            [ArrivalDate] => 21/07/2017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ArrivalTime] => 582
            [ProductID] => 397
            [ArrivalDate] => 22/07/2017
        )

)
```

Comment: 1 for the Answer and we don't know that json is correct anyway your code is fine

Comment: That json is not valid,because it lack of key's and value's quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your "json" string with [] and quotes, of course (or check, why it not wrapped earlier):

```
[{"ArrivalTime": 300,"ProductID": 198,"ArrivalDate": "21 / 07 / 2017"}, {"ArrivalTime": 582,"ProductID": 397,"ArrivalDate": "22 / 07 / 2017"}]
```

Then it will be correct json format and json_decode() create correct array.

Comment: Is this valid json?

Comment: If with [ and ] - yes. Then it will be array.

Comment: Your right, in my example a forgot quotes, and i've checked string with them :)

Answer (score 0):

the json is invalid even if we add "[]" (array brackets)

- value should be in the any one of the format :

  > string, number,object,array,true,false,null

in your case there is a date in the value field change it to string by enclosing ""(double quotes)

- the key in your json is a string 
  for json key the string should be enclosed by ""(double quotes)

> " chars "

offical documentation : http://www.json.org/

the correct json format for your json is

```
   [{
    "ArrivalTime": 300,
    "ProductID": 198,
    "ArrivalDate": "21 / 07 / 2017"
}, {
    "ArrivalTime": 582,
    "ProductID": 397,
    "ArrivalDate": "22 / 07 / 2017"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid json format. But if you have such kinda string try this code:

```
$string = "{ArrivalTime:300, ProductID:198, ArrivalDate:21/07/2017}, {ArrivalTime:582, ProductID:397, ArrivalDate:22/07/2017}";


$key = $value = $resultArray= array();

$arrayJson = explode('}, ', $string);



foreach ($arrayJson as $arrayJsonRep) {

    $repJson = str_replace('{', '', $arrayJsonRep);
    $repJson = str_replace('}', '', $repJson);
    $repJsonExp = explode(', ', $repJson);

    foreach ($repJsonExp as $x) {

        $repJsonExpfirst=  explode(':', $x); 
        array_push($key, $repJsonExpfirst[0]);
        array_push($value, $repJsonExpfirst[1]);
    }

    $finalArray = array_combine($key, $value);
    array_push($resultArray, $finalArray);
}



print_r($resultArray);
```