# How to turn strings into arrays using regex pattern using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How can I separate the challenge string below into an array with a regex pattern?

For example:

```
$str = '{varA: "value, A", varB: "value:B", varC: "value C", varD: "value\"D\""}';

// remove both curved brackets
$trimStr = substr($str, 1, strlen($str)-1);
preg_match_all("/(.*?):\"(.*?)\",/sm", $trimStr, $m);  // would like the regex to ignore the ',' and double quote in the value string too
```

Into an array where

```
arr[0] = 'varA: "value, A"';
arr[1] = 'varB: "value:B"';
arr[2] = 'varC: "value C"';
arr[3] = 'varC: "value \"D\""';
```

Comment: [What did you try?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please share the regex pattern you've tried and explain how it fails (doesn't match anything, matches wrong value...).

Comment: have updated the questions with what i got at the moment

Comment: Not sure why the question was closed now that it has full details.

Comment: The string $str contains a Javascript object notation. It's not JSON! I haven't found a good solution to convert such a notation into a PHP array.

Comment: @davidlee: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729051/php-reading-invalid-json-with-json-decode first answer with preg_replace and json_decode. That works for your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give optional spacing between the `:` and `"` and you need to change delimiter to `,` or end of line.

```
(.*?):\h*\"(.*?)\"(?:,|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aAyrQA/1/

or:

```
\{?(.*?):\h*\"(.*?)\"(?:,|\}|$)
```

and you can remove the `$trimStr = substr($str, 1, strlen($str)-1);`.

full PHP example:

```
preg_match_all('/\{?(.*?):\h*\"(.*?)\"(?:,|\}|$)/', '{varA: "value, A", varB: "value:B", varC: "value C", varD: "value\"D\""}', $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
    $arr[] = $match . ' :"' . $matches[2][$key] . '"';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/0nJqW

Answer (score 1):

In your example it seems like you don't need to use regex at all, just remove the curly brackets and explode your string into an array. Since your elements are already comma separated, just use the correct delimiter.

```
$arr = explode(', ', $str);
```

However if you insist on using regex, here's an expression that will match your elements:

```
var\w+\:\s\".+?(?=\,|})
```

Comment: how could i able to escape the comma and double quote in the value?

Comment: The explode works only if there is no comma in the values. However, it would break if there exist , in the values.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks for the tips. Will update the ques

Answer (score 0):

`/(.*?):\"(.*?)\",/sm` => `/{?((.*?): ?"(.*?)")[,}]/`
[try regex](https://regexr.com/5jj0v)

PHP code:

```
$str = '{varA: "value A", varB: "value:B", varC: "value C", varD: "value"D""}';
$pattern = '/{?((.*?): ?"(.*?)")[,}]/';
$arr = [];

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
  $arr[] = $match;
}
print_r($arr);
```